# wpdb select table no arguments

Tags: wordpress

I am using new wpdb for accessing database with wordpress.

```
$mydb = new wpdb($username,$password,$database,$hostname);
$sql = $mydb->prepare("SELECT * FROM " . $table);
$results = $mydb->get_results($sql);
```

This line produces error:

```
$sql = $mydb->prepare("SELECT * FROM " . $table);
```

wpdb::prepare was called **incorrectly**. wpdb::prepare() requires at least two arguments.

All below statements produce same error:

```
$sql = $mydb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table");
$sql = $mydb->prepare("SELECT * FROM '%s'", $table);
```

How do I write it without arguments?

(I am using wordpress 3.5)

Answer (score 0):

Take the single quotes off from '%s' in your last example and that should work assuming $table is a valid table name.

Edit: $wpdb->prepare() works similar to php's sprintf() on a more limited scale.  If you just pass it a single parameter, it doesn't *do* anything.  See Andrew Nacin's post on this after 3.5 was released: http://make.wordpress.org/core/2012/12/12/php-warning-missing-argument-2-for-wpdb-prepare/

The second parameter will replace the first instance of a replaceable character set, i.e. %s, %d or %f, and third parameter will replace the second instance, and so on.

Comment: No, it doesnt work. Table is a valid name, this works fine: $sql = $mydb->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE album ='%s'", $album);

Comment: Yea, you're right.  Looks like prepare() adds single quotes to the replacement, so you're ending up with `SELECT * FROM 'wp_posts'` which is throwing the error.  Do you need to have a variable table name?  What are you trying to do that requires it?

Comment: Even like this: $sql = $mydb->prepare("SELECT * FROM playlist"); the same error appears (playlist is table name)

Comment: Right, because you're not passing a second parameter.  If you're not going to be replacing anything because there isn't any user input, just skip the prepare() step.

Comment: How do I write this without prepare?

Comment: Just pass the raw sql to get_results(), `$results = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM playlist');`  Careful though, make sure there's no user input on anything that you're running without escaping.

Comment: So if I just read the data from the database without any changes I dont really need prepare?

Comment: Yea, prepare() is used to escape potentially malicious data input by users.  If you were doing something like `SELECT * FROM playlist WHERE id = 5` and you got "5" from something a user clicked on or typed in, then you'd want to escape it using prepare.